# JQuery accordeon

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток!
У меня маленькая проблема.
Сделал аккордеон своими руками(Jquery). Обычного плана, при нажатии на ссылку открывается соседний section,а к ссылке добавляеться .an_back.
При нажатии на другую ссылку также открываеться соседний section и добавляеться класс к этой ссылке и убираеться у предыдущей и закрываеться предыдущий section.

Как сделать так, чтобы при повторном нажатии на одну и ту же ссылку убирался класс .an_back. (section закрываеться).

HTML:

```
<ul class="service-list">
    <li class="service-item">
      <a href="#" class="service-show">Юрист</a>
      <section>
       <h6>Юрист</h6>
        <p class="fw400">Обязанности:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Консультирование клиентов по услугам компании (регистрация юридических лиц, внесение изменений);</li>
          <li>Подготовка документов для проведения регистрационных действий (регистрация ООО, регистрация ИП, изменения).</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="fw400">Требования:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Высшее образование;</li>
          <li>Обязательно наличие практического опыта по регистрации юридических лиц и внесению изменений;</li>
          <li>Навыки общения с людьми, приветливость и доброжелательность;</li>
          <li>Настойчивость в достижении цели и настроенность на получение результата;</li>
          <li>Умение работать с большими объемами информации;</li>
          <li>Желание работать и зарабатывать;</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="fw400">Условия</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Конкурентный оклад + ежемесячная премия от объема выполненной работы.</li>
          <li>Полный рабочий день, с 9 до 18;</li>
          <li>Работа в современном офисе (м. Сходненская, напротив 46 ИФНС);</li>
          <li>Оформление в полном соответствии с ТК РФ, зарплата "белая";</li>
          <li>Испытательный срок - 3 мес. (без уменьшения зарплаты).</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="d-btn show-order-form cboxElement">Откликнуться на вакансию</a>
      </section>
    </li>
     <li class="service-item">
      <a href="#" class="service-show">Специалист по маркетингу и рекламе</a>
      <section>
       <h6>Юрист</h6>
        <p class="fw400">Обязанности:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Подготовка документов для проведения регистрационных действий (регистрация ООО, регистрация ИП, изменения).</li>
          <li>Взаимодействие с помощниками юристов, контроль их работы.</li>
          <li>Сопровождение выполнения заказа на всех этапах.</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="fw400">Требования:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Высшее образование;</li>
          <li>Обязательно наличие практического опыта по регистрации юридических лиц и внесению изменений;</li>
          <li>Умение работать с большими объемами информации;</li>
          <li>Желание работать и зарабатывать;</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="fw400">Условия</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Конкурентный оклад + ежемесячная премия от объема выполненной работы.</li>
          <li>Полный рабочий день, с 9 до 18;</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="d-btn show-order-form cboxElement">Откликнуться на вакансию</a>
      </section>
    </li>
     <li class="service-item">
      <a href="#" class="service-show">Помощник юриста</a>
      <section>
       <h6>Юрист (регистрация юридических лиц и индивидуальных предпринимателей)</h6>
        <p class="fw400">Обязанности:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Консультирование внесение изменений);</li>
          <li>Подготовка (регистрация ООО, регистрация ИП, изменения).</li>
          <li>Взаимодействие с помощниками юристов, контроль их работы.</li>
          <li>Сопровождение выполнения заказа на всех этапах.</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="fw400">Требования:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Высшее образование;</li>
          <li>Обязательно наличие практического опыта по регистрации юридических лиц и внесению изменений;</li>
          <li>Навыки общения с людьми, приветливость и доброжелательность;</li>
          <li>Настойчивость в достижении цели и настроенность на получение результата;</li>
          <li>Умение работать с большими объемами информации;</li>
          <li>Желание работать и зарабатывать;</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="fw400">Условия</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Конкурентный.</li>
          <li>Оформление </li>
          <li>Испытательный срок - 3 мес. (без уменьшения зарплаты).</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="d-btn show-order-form cboxElement">Откликнуться на вакансию</a>
      </section>
    </li>
     <li class="service-item">
      <a href="#" class="service-show">Помощник бухгалтера</a>
      <section>
       <h6>Юрист (регистрация юридических лиц и индивидуальных предпринимателей)</h6>
        <p class="fw400">Обязанности:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Взаимодействие с помощниками юристов, контроль их работы.</li>
          <li>Сопровождение выполнения заказа на всех этапах.</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="fw400">Требования:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Высшее образование;</li>
          <li>Обязательно наличие практического опыта по регистрации юридических лиц и внесению изменений;</li>
          <li>Умение работать с большими объемами информации;</li>
          <li>Желание работать и зарабатывать;</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="fw400">Условия</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Конкурентный оклад + ежемесячная премия от объема выполненной работы.</li>
          <li>Испытательный срок - 3 мес. (без уменьшения зарплаты).</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="d-btn show-order-form cboxElement">Откликнуться на вакансию</a>
      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
var caption = $(".service-list").find(".service-show"),
    content = $(".service-item").find("section").hide();

caption.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    content.not($(this).next(content)).removeClass('active').slideUp(600);
    caption.removeClass('an_back');

    $(this).next(content).toggleClass('active').slideToggle(600);
    $(this).addClass('an_back');

});
```

});

Ссылка на CodePen:

[Ссылка для удобства правки](http://codepen.io/GriAl/pen/rVgbbQ)

Comment: У меня он прекрасно закрывается без всякого исправления кода ;)

Comment: Дело не в закрытии.

Comment: Нужно при повторном нажатии на ссылку удалить класс .an_back. Сейчас он удаляеться только при нажатии на другую ссылку

Comment: Извините, не внимательно прочитал вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например можно [так](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNaaPO):

```
$(function() {
  var caption = $(".service-list").find(".service-show"),
    content = $(".service-item").find("section").hide();

  caption.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // сохраняем текущий открытый блок
    var activeContent = content.filter('.active');
    // закрываем текущий открытый блок
    activeContent.removeClass('active').slideUp(600);
    caption.removeClass('an_back');
    // выходим если после "нажатой" ссылки идет текущий открытый блок 
    if ($(this).next(content).is(activeContent)) return;
    // открываем блок после "нажатой" ссылки
    $(this).next(content).addClass('active').slideDown(600);
    $(this).addClass('an_back');
  });
});
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо)

Comment: А можно на словах, пояснение? А то не совсем понятны ваши вставки.

Comment: @tutankhamun, лучше все таки не делать `return` а инвертировать условие и внести последующий код внутрь.

Comment: @maxwell, возможно, с точки зрения читаемости кода, вы правы

Comment: @tutankhamun, помимо читаемости — по мере роста функции мы явно будем видеть блок который вполняется, а который нет, т.е. это снижает возможные ошибки (например, кто-то другой добавит код в конец функции и будет удивляться чего это он не отрабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

А если использовать метод toggleClass()? Немного измененный код

```
  $(function() {
    var $caption = $(".service-list").find(".service-show"),
      $content = $(".service-item").find("section").hide();

    $caption.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $current = $(e.currentTarget),
          $active = current.parent().find('.active');
      $active.toggleClass('active').slideUp(600);
      $current.toggleClass('an_back');
      if ($(this).next($content).is($active)) {
        return;
      };
      $(this).next($content).toggleClass("active").slideDown(600);
    });
  });
```